# Angular HttpClient observables fire repeatedly

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables

The setup is as follows. Somebody calls my angular application with a url that includes an id to display the properties of the object with that id. Just like an online shop.

`http://myFrontend/productDetails/10`

I then use `ActivatedRoute` to get the id (`10`) and pass it on the `HttpClient` to fetch the requested data from the backend.

```
this.route.params.pipe(map(params => params.id)).subscribe(id => {
   const params = new HttpParams().set('id', id);
   this.httpClient.get<Product>('http://myBackend/product/', {params})
      .subscribe(product => this.product = product);
});
```

The problem gets visible when a user navigates, from this route to the same route for a diffrent product. so lets say You are at `http://myFrontend/productDetails/10`. There is an `Observable` that waits for the backend to return the product with the id `10` and store it into a component variable. Then you click `next` to navigate to `http://myFrontend/productDetails/11`. A new `Observable` is created that waits for the product with the id `11` to store it into the same component variable.

I don't really get why, but the first `Observable` that returns product `10` fires again, when I want to fetch product `11`. Including a repeated http-request to `http://myBackend/product/?id=10`. Which in turn causes a race-condition because bothe of the the `Subscriptions` write their result the the same component variable.

I could stop that from happening by unsbscribing immediately after the observable returned for the first time or by piping it through `take(1)` but i'd like to understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.route.params` fires every time the params changes. Which means it will create a new subscription every time the parameter changes. As you have in your example, it is generally an antipattern to have nested subscriptions.
If you want to chain observables, you can use the so-called higher-order mapping operators, e.g., concatMap, mergeMap, switchMap, or exhaustMap. Another thing that you can do is not to subscribe explicitly by calling subscribe, but instead, you could utilize the async pipe directly in the template. This will unsubscribe automatically, which can prevent memory leaks (it's not a problem in your case.)
Try this instead:

```
this.route.params.pipe(concatMap(params => {
   const p = new HttpParams().set('id', params.id);
   return this.httpClient.get<Product>('http://myBackend/product/', {p})       
}).subscribe(product => this.product = product);
```

or

```
let product$ = this.route.params.pipe(concatMap(params => {
       const p = new HttpParams().set('id', params.id);
       return this.httpClient.get<Product>('http://myBackend/product/', {p})       
    })

...in the template

<div *ngIf="product$ | async as product">....</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do get the solution and why it's bad practice but can you explain why the first observable fires again ? I thout these are supposed to be short lived. Thats why I never bothered to clean up all these subscribtions.

Comment: Observables shine when it comes to a long-lived operation, like listening to and reacting to a specific event. In your case, the route.params observables for route params changes, and every time it changes, it fires an event. You can also use the snapshot property if you just want the param for a given time without using observables.

Comment: I was expecting route.params to be long lived. So we agree on that one. But why is httpClient.get long lived? I was expecting it to fire just once.